# Send photo back without saving it (aiogram)

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, aiogram

I want to recieve a photo from user, save it somewhere but not on my disk (in veriable or dictionary) and send it back in a step. I have FSM, so how can I sent user's photo after some steps?

```
@dp.message_handler(content_types=['photo'],state=UserState.photo)
async def get_photo(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):

    print(message)
    print("\n\n\n\n")
    
    await message.photo[-1].download(f'{message.from_user.id}.png')
    photo = open(f'{message.from_user.id}.png', 'rb')
    await bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo)

    await UserState.main_text.set()
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can try to save it in io.BytesIO object by passing it into await message.photo[-1].download like this

```
fp = io.BytesIO()
await message.photo[-1].download(fp)
```

Then you can send it by using InputFile from aiogram